# Testing Database Exists TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, entity-framework-5

I am in need of some testing advice.

I know that it's generally bad practice to hit a database in Unit Tests except in exceptional circumstances.

I'm taking a TDD approach to an MVC project using EF. My first test is:

```
void DatabaseShouldExist() { ... }
```

I would like to know... Is this an exceptional circumstance?

I want to check that EF generated the DB and my next test will be to check if it contains the the correct seed data.

How would you go about testing this?

Should it be tested?

Comment: Mocking framework. NSubstitute.

Comment: I disagree.  If you're testing a DAO, it makes no sense to do anything other than hit the database.  Once that's done, then classes that have a dependency on the DAO can rely on mocks.  I wouldn't write a test to see if the database exists.  I would assume it a priori.

Comment: It's not bad practice at all to do *integration test*. The only thing is, it's not the same as "unit" tests, but it's very useful. Further, I fully agree with @duffymo. If the database isn't created you'll notice it, don't worry.

Comment: The problem is that I want to know when to "Start" TDD. I want to start using it right away... not wait until... code starts creeping in. What if someone messes up the seed method? I want to ensure that the table contains correct data but first I want to check that it exists before that the ab must exist... I don't know where to draw the line. There should be a distinct guideline on when to start TDD. :/

Comment: Why not to test business logic first? Is it really that important to check that some data exists?

As I understand, you want to test MVC app. If I were you, I'd have started from controllers. I'd wrote tests for them (if it was possible at all), moved business logic from them to other classes (services perhaps?), and probably covered models (if not anemic). I wouldn't be bothered by data if it wasn't requested by business.

Comment: @AlexeyGroshev I'll consider starting from Controllers but is there anything actually wrong with what I've done?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign , I wouldn't say so, but it's considered to be a bad practice. Don't hit database in your tests if it can be avoided. In the ideal world, you'd have everything mocked.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test behaviour, so not if a DB exists or not on it own.
As suggested in comments, start with business logic.
TDD starts small and is iterative, don't dive into DB logic test 1.

Simplistic example (For a App to store movies)

```
Test 1 - shouldAddAMoveToList()
Test 2 - shouldBeAbleToRetrieveAMovieFromList()
Test 3 - shouldPersistAMovieBeweenSessions() // Could Be DB here
```

When using TDD, pick something simple first. The DB part should come into play a bit later on.

Personally I would avoid testing against a DB with a Unit Test, and save this for Integration tests. DAO pattern is good for this as you could persist in memory, or simply mock the DB side in Unit Tests.

Unit Tests should try to adhere to the [FIRST principle](http://www.beyondcoding.net/articles/firstprinciples.html), introducing Databases can slow down tests, and prevent them being independent (unless clearing DB each time) - At very least try to use in-memory database for Unit Tests

Comment: Sorry what is the DAO pattern?

Comment: Data Access Object - See this link. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm

Comment: thanks Mike. I'm using Entity Framework for Data access. It uses POCO so in that sense mocking repositories seems sensible.